# fortran: what does real variable(i,j) do

Tags: variables, fortran, definition, fortran77

In fortran if I define a variable as follows

```
 real dummy(5,5)
```

what does the output of "dummy" mean?

```
 print *, dummy

 dummy   0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       5184.52539       4.58785117E-41   5121.91309       4.58785117E-41   1.40129846E-45   0.00000000       1.40129846E-45   8.40779079E-45   8.29111587E-39   0.00000000       5142.97266       4.58785117E-41  -9.61458209E+11   4.59121429E-41  -9.61840873E+11   4.59121429E-41   5.18480432E-44   0.00000000      -9.61840873E+11   4.59121429E-41   5.18480432E-44
```

Answer (score 2):

With the first command, you create a 2D array with the name of `dummy`, type `real`, and shape `(5,5)`.

The second command prints out the contents of `dummy` to the screen. It would most certainly not have printed the word `dummy`, but would have printed 25 values, the contents of `dummy`, in the order `(1,1) (2,1) (3,1) (4,1) (5,1) (1,2) (2,2) ... (5,5)`

The fact that some of those values are zero, while others have random values suggests that you haven't initialised the array with any values, and they just have the `real` interpretation of whatever was in that memory location before.

You can always set all values to zero with this line:

```
dummy = 0.0
```